# Calling a function for a generate button

Tags: reactjs, firebase, button

I have a page where a user can search a database for a given condition, then the data is returned with another button that the user can use to add information back to the database.  However whenever I click on the second button, the page reloads.  I can't get so much as a console.log to go in.  I'm new to react and could use any help at all.

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { database } from '../firebase';



const byPropKey = (propertyName, value) => () => ({
    [propertyName]: value,
});

class Search extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            users: null,
            searchCondition: "",
            friend: ""
        }
        // this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    }
    onSubmit = (event) => {
        let {
            searchCondition,
            friend
        } = this.state;
        database.searchConditions(searchCondition).then(snapshot => 
            this.setState(() => ({ users: snapshot.val() }))
        );

        event.preventDefault();
    }
    messageSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log("Click")
    }

    render(){
        let {
            users,
            searchCondition,
            friend
        } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Search for conditions</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="search">
                        <input
                        value={searchCondition}
                        onChange={event => this.setState(byPropKey('searchCondition', event.target.value))}
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Condition to Search For"
                        />
                        <button className="friendButton"
                        onClick="x"
                        type="submit">
                            Search
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </form>

                    {!!users && <UserList users={users} />}
            </div>
                )
            }
        }
        let UserList = ({ users, message }) =>
                    <div>
                            <h2>List of Usernames and Conditions of your Search</h2>
                            {Object.keys(users).map(key =>
                                <div key={key}>{users[key].username} : {users[key].condition}
                        <form>
                            <div className="search">
                                <input
                                    value={message} 
                                    onChange={console.log("test")}
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Message for this User"
                                />
                                <button className="messageButton"
                                    onClick={console.log(message)}
                                    type="submit">
                                    Message
                        </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                            )}
                    </div>






export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place the event.preventDefault() at the beginning of the event handler?

It should prevent the default behaviour imediately as the event gets fired.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

a couple things i can see, youre even.preventDefault() should be at the top of the page, you said it was reloading so thats unwanted behavior. second you should set state within the then, generally speaking in my experience that doesnt work- i believe due to setState being asynchronous or something of that nature.

i would rewrite your submit like this

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let {
        searchCondition,
        friend
    } = this.state;
    let value;
    database.searchConditions(searchCondition).then(snapshot => 
        value = snapshot.val
    );
    this.setState(() => ({ users: value) }))
}
```

also likely the reason your "messageSubmit()" was not console logging is because youre using a submit handler not a click handler so everytime your clicked you were reloading the page.

cheers

Comment: ever figure it out?